# SQL Server: Stored Procedure (Newbie)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have done a few web searches but cant find anything that can really fix the issue i have with 1 x database table and 2 x stored procedures.  I am a newbie to this subject so any help is much appriechiated.

I have 2 stored procedures.  One of these queries the raw data from another database (GetRawDataFromIHistorian) and the other (GasNominationsRawData_Insert) should when executed INSERT this data into a table.

My first SP works but i cant seem to insert this into my table named GasRawData.  The message displayed when tring to execute the Insert SP is...

"Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure GasNominationsRawData_Insert, Line 0
Procedure or function 'GasNominationsRawData_Insert' expects parameter '@timestamp', which was not supplied."

My first SP (GetRawDataFromIHistorian) looks like this...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRawDataFromIHistorian] 

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT [timestamp], Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) AS TagName,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), ROUND(value, 2)) AS Value
FROM 
OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN,'
    SELECT timestamp, tagname, value
    FROM ihRawData
    WHERE tagname = "UMIS.99FC9051.F_CV"
    OR tagname = "UMIS.99F851C.F_CV"
    AND timestamp BETWEEN ''2011-10-18 05:00:00.000'' AND ''2011-10-19 06:00:00.000''
    AND samplingmode =Calculated
    AND calculationmode =Average
    AND intervalmilliseconds =1h
    ORDER BY tagname, timestamp
    ')
```

And my INSERT SP (GasNominationsRawData_Insert) is the following...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GasNominationsRawData_Insert]
    @timestamp DATETIME,
    @TagName NVARCHAR(50),
    @Value REAL

AS

INSERT INTO dbo.GasRawData (timestamp,
                TagName,
                Value)
VALUES (@timestamp,
        @TagName,
        @Value);

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS NewRecordID;
```

I simply just want to take the results from the GetRawDataFromIHistorian query and use the GasNominationsRawData_Insert to populat the GasRawData table.

I have 4 columns in my GasRawData table...

```
RecordID (PK, int, not null)
timestamp (datetime, not null)
tagname (nvarchar(50), not null)
value (real, not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be when you call the procedure GasNominationsRawData_Insert, as you are not passing the parameters expected. Can you show us how you are executing that stored procedure?. Also, you should have only one stored procedure, try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GasNominationsRawData_Insert
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.GasRawData (timestamp,TagName,Value)
SELECT [timestamp], Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) AS TagName,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), ROUND(value, 2)) AS Value
FROM 
OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN,'
    SELECT timestamp, tagname, value
    FROM ihRawData
    WHERE tagname = "UMIS.99FC9051.F_CV"
    OR tagname = "UMIS.99F851C.F_CV"
    AND timestamp BETWEEN ''2011-10-18 05:00:00.000'' AND ''2011-10-19 06:00:00.000''
    AND samplingmode =Calculated
    AND calculationmode =Average
    AND intervalmilliseconds =1h
    ORDER BY tagname, timestamp
    ')
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message shows that you arent passing a value to the @timestamp parameter which is required

Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure GasNominationsRawData_Insert, Line 0 Procedure or function 'GasNominationsRawData_Insert' expects parameter '@timestamp', which was not supplied.

Solution is to either pass in the parameter or make it optional by adding a default value.

If you can post the code where you are calling the procedures we can probably help more